# How to create a gender split ( Ratio ) for different products / Categories and its change over time

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, data-analysis, percentage

I'm completely new here, after diving forum after forum to get an answer about this, I decided to build it myself, but it's too long. I would appreciate contributions with simpler solutions or scenarios. I'll try to be as detailed as possible so brace yourself, this will be a long thread, here we go:

**Problem:** The client wants to know if this can be done with SQL Server: **What is the gender *split* for each of our *programs*, and how did it vary over time during the last quarter of the year?**

And they also provided the following Column names: **ClientID**, **ClientName**, **Program**, **StartDate**, **Gender**, **Location**.

Not very complicated if it were made in tools like Excel, Tableau or PowerBI, but it really got me thinking HOW to do it with SQL.

So, first I decided to create two programs for the sake of brevity: Program_A, Program_B

Then, I would make a pivot table and run a query that should look something like this:

[image: Gender Ratio Variation over Time]

Anyways, on with the testing. **First** I created a table named General and fed it with some data (I apologize for the long repetitive code block ahead):

```
  CREATE TABLE General(
    ClientID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ClientName varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Program varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
    StartDate date,
    Gender varchar(30) NULL, 
    Location varchar(30) NULL)


INSERT [dbo].[General] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('John Doe', 'Program_A', '2020-10-01', 'Male', 'US')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Chewbaka Girl', 'Program_B', '2020-10-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Jane Doe', 'Program_A', '2020-12-01', 'Male', 'UK')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ( 'Carol Smith', 'Program_A', '2020-11-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Pedro Mostaza', 'Program_B', '2020-11-01', 'Male', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Jean Plurier', 'Program_A', '2020-12-01', 'Male', 'UK')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Nicole Kiteman', 'Program_A', '2020-12-01', 'Female', 'US')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Sonia Cepeda', 'Program_B', '2020-10-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Alejandra Moncayo', 'Program_A', '2020-11-01', 'Female', 'UK')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Britanny Royce', 'Program_A', '2020-11-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Arnold Lotfrey', 'Program_A', '2020-10-01', 'Male', 'US')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Richard Books', 'Program_B', '2020-11-01', 'Male', 'UK')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Camero Lovely', 'Program_B', '2020-11-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Henry Lakes', 'Program_B', '2020-11-01', 'Male', 'UK')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Cameron Lovely', 'Program_B', '2020-12-01', 'Female', 'US')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Paula Mint', 'Program_A', '2020-11-01', 'Female', 'US')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Shirley Timer', 'Program_A', '2020-12-01', 'Female', 'CA')

INSERT [dbo].[Fellows] ([ClientName], [Program], [StartDate], [Gender], [Location])
VALUES ('Andrew Rocks', 'Program_A', '2020-10-01', 'Female', 'CA')
```

**Second**, I created a small query using a CTE including WITH and CASE to split the Gender column into Male / Female into two different ones and transforming their values into numbers, so I could later add the percentage:

```
WITH CTE
AS (SELECT Program, StartDate,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender='Male' THEN 1  END) As Male,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender='Female' THEN 1  END) As Female,
COUNT(CASE WHEN (Gender='' OR Gender IS Null) THEN 1 END) As 'NotAssigned'
FROM General 
GROUP BY Program, StartDate)
SELECT Program, StartDate, Male, Female,
 Male*100.0/(Male + Female) as Male_Ratio,
 Female*100.0/(Male + Female) as Female_Ratio
 INTO Program_GenderBreakdown
from CTE;
```

**Third**, I also transformed the StartDate into Months to make it easy to read:

```
SELECT * INTO Results 
FROM (
  SELECT
    Program, Male_Ratio AS Percentage, StartDate, 'Male' AS Gender
  FROM Program_GenderBreakdown
) T --temporary name
PIVOT (
  SUM(Percentage)
  FOR StartDate
  IN (
    [2020-10-01], 
    [2020-11-01],
    [2020-12-01]
    )
) AS PvtMale
UNION ALL --then unite both male and female pivots
--query For female
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    Program, Female_Ratio AS Percentage, StartDate,'Female' AS Gender
  FROM Program_GenderBreakdown
) T
PIVOT (
  SUM(Percentage)
  FOR StartDate
  IN (
    [2020-10-01], 
    [2020-11-01],
    [2020-12-01]
    )
) AS PvtFemale
```

**Fourth** Using CAST I transformed the dates (with 2 decimals for aesthetics) into Month Names

```
SELECT Program, Gender, CAST([2020-10-01] AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS 'October', CAST([2020-11-01] AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS 'November', CAST([2020-12-01] AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS 'December',
CASE WHEN [2020-10-01]=0 THEN -1 ELSE CAST((([2020-11-01]/[2020-10-01])-1) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) END AS 'MoMOct-Nov',
CASE WHEN [2020-11-01]=0 THEN -1 ELSE CAST((([2020-12-01]/[2020-11-01])-1) AS DECIMAL(19,2)) END AS 'MoMNov-Dec'
FROM PivotT
ORDER BY Program, Gender DESC
```

The outcome wasn't as I thought because the table looks inverted of what I wanted, but calculations worked so far. here's the final outcome:

[image]

**Conclusion:** Althought calculations work, how do I make the table look as originally intended,and is it even worth it? thanks in advance for any help with this. or even if you want to pass by and give me feedback about this thread it will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using conditional group by, as given below:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(Program,'_',datename(month,startdate)) as ProgramMonth, 
convert(decimal(5,2),(COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' then 1 end) * 1.0/COUNT(*)) * 100) as MaleCount,
convert(decimal(5,2),(COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' then 1 end) * 1.0/count(*)) * 100) as FemaleCount
FROM general
group by CONCAT(Program,'_',datename(month,startdate))
```

| ProgramMonth | MaleCount | FemaleCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Program_A_December | 50.00 | 50.00 |
| Program_A_November | 0.00 | 100.00 |
| Program_A_October | 66.67 | 33.33 |
| Program_B_December | 0.00 | 100.00 |
| Program_B_November | 75.00 | 25.00 |
| Program_B_October | 0.00 | 100.00 |

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for this. Do you have any ideas for the second part, variation over time?

Comment: @DanielAlcivar, I am not getting the second part. can you explain more ?

Comment: basically the client asks to  see how the gender ratio, varied over time (in this case Month over Month variation)